# Perl: Unable to install PadWalker module

Tags: perl

I am new to Perl. I have used CPAN, CPANM, manual install using makeFile to install PadWalker module (tried various version). No matter what I do, I am seeing the same error which is shown below:

```
mv PadWalker.xsc PadWalker.c
icc -c   -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -mp1 -fPIC -fp_port -I/usr/local/include -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -O3   -DVERSION=\"2.0\" -DXS_VERSION=\"2.0\"  "-I/opt/ORACLE/app/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/client_64_1/perl/lib/5.14.1/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/CORE"   PadWalker.c
/bin/sh: icc: command not found**
```

I think this has to do with icc but not sure what that is.

```
make: [PadWalker.o] Error 127
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `perl` was compiled using `icc`. This same compiler is needed to compile the C component of PadWalker , but it isn't found on your system (or at least not in the PATH). Install it using the same package manager that you used to install `perl`.